# How to reference two times to a single footnote in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

I try to reference to a single footnote in a few places in the text. However, with the code below, I've got two footnotes with the same content.

```
---
title: "My document"
output: html_document
---

One part of the text [^1].

Two pages later [^1].

[^1]: My footnote
```

[image]

Is it possible to reference more than once to a specific footnote using `rmarkdown`?

Comment: See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1603, a general solution does not seem to exist yet. But I guess (hope) there are solution specific to HTML document.

Comment: If you are open to knitr 
 and external packages like `fixfoot` see this [reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I used html tags which worked really well. Whatever you  want as superscript just put between the  <\sup> like below:

```
<sup> text </sup>
```

jan 6 2023 update:
now I use quarto which is eally easy as you can just use do[^1]

[^1]footnote text

Answer (score 1):

My workaround here is to just do it manually using inline latex mathmode (e.g, `\(^2\)` ).. Annoying, but even if they had a solution, you'd have to remember the citation number anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with latex solution if you do not have many footnotes per page. By latex solution I mean:

(in Markdown, use Latex to superscript the footnote number)

First part$^1$

(and the next one)

Second part$^2$

(at the end of your text add *** to create a line across the document)

(under the line, add the text below:)

1, 2: Text for your footnote

On the other hand, there is a thread created on this specific R-Markdown bug. Maybe take a look at it, in this [link](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1603).

Hope I helped somehow.